# Define a quantile group in a dataframe with the data source in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a quantile information from a dataframe in a named vector using the next code:

```
library(tidyverse)

quant_mpg <- mtcars %>% 
  pull(mpg) %>% 
  quantile(probs = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

And I want to cut this quantile in a summary dataframe created post:

```
grouped_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(quantile = cut(mpg, quant_mpg, labels = FALSE))
```

Obtaning the next output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl   mpg quantile
  <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
1     4  26.7        9
2     6  19.7        6
3     8  15.1        2
```

Is there a way I can make this straightforward for the grouped variable without defining the `quant_mpg` vector. I need it this way bacause I have several group variables and grouped dataframes and I need to obtain the quantiles without much processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the column from original data

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl) %>% 
   summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
   mutate(quantile = cut(mpg,  quantile(mtcars[['mpg']], #####
            probs = seq(0, 1, 0.1)), labels = FALSE))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl   mpg quantile
#  <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
#1     4  26.7        9
#2     6  19.7        6
#3     8  15.1        2
```